# In vim netrw using mf, how to highlight file with name starting by '.' dot symbol?

Tags: vim, netrw

When trying to `mf` mark files named `.*` in `netrw`, `vim` provides no visual feedback. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It works perfectly, [here](http://i.imgur.com/9y6saQM.png). Maybe a colorscheme problem? Or a netrw bug?

Comment: Before posting question I checked the Vim Touch Android, and it had the same issue. But now I'm more convinced it's a bug. Will check other vim versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug, as mentioned in romainl comment.

Fixed by updating vim with

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fcwu-tw/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install vim
```